# Symfony Api Platform filtering entities after they are retrieved from persistance layer

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, symfony-4.3

I have a situation where I need to extract objects from persistent layer after applying [some filters](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#filters) and then do some maths on object data and filter base of another query parameter.

Use case: Get all the location which are within the radius of 10km of given latitude and longitude.

Which can be translated into an api endpoint as:

**https://api.testdomain.com/api/location?latitude=10&longitude=20&distance=10**

I have location entity with:

```
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={
 *      "longitude": "start",
 *      "latitude":"start",
 *      "city":"partial",
 *      "postal_code":"partial",
 *      "address":"partial",
 *    }
 * )
 class Location
 {
  ... 

   public function withinDistance($latitude, $longitude, $distance):?bool
   {
      $location_distance=$this->distanceFrom($latitude,$longitude);
      return $location_distance<=$distance;
   }

 }
```

Since `latitude` and `longitude` are entity attributes search will be applied and sql query filter is applied, while `distance` is not an attribute we have to apply this kind of filter after all object are retrieved from db, which   is mystery for me.

I am looking to put following code somewhere after query result is returned :

```
 public function getCollection($collection){
  //return after search filtered applied on location.longitute and location.latitude
  $all_locations_of_lat_long=$collection;
  $locations_within_distance=[];
  $query = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->query;
  $lat= $query->get('latitude',0);
  $lng= $query->get('longitude',0);
  $distance= $query->get('distance',null);

  if($distance==null){
    return $all_locations_of_lat_long;
  }

  for($all_locations_of_lat_long as $location){
    if($location->withinDistance($lat,$lng,$distance))
       $locations_within_distance[]=$location;
  }

  return $locations_within_distance; 
 }
```

What is correct why to apply such filter on entity object collections returned ? I don't think 
ORM filter will be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that its easy to filter entities by writing a [custom controller action](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers) and filtering entities after they are retrieved from persistence layer. This could mean I had to fetch all records and then filter which is very costly.

Alternate option was, as suggested by [qdequippe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58389667/416100), was simply write a custom filter to find distance as follow:

Define a distance filter:

> src/Filter/DistanceFilter

```
<?php
namespace App\Filter;


use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\AbstractContextAwareFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGeneratorInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

final class DistanceFilter extends AbstractContextAwareFilter
{

    const DISTANCE=10.0;
    const LAT='latitude';
    const LON='longitude';

    private $appliedAlready=false;

    protected function filterProperty(string $property, $value, QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, QueryNameGeneratorInterface $queryNameGenerator, string $resourceClass, string $operationName = null)
    {
        // otherwise filter is applied to order and page as well
        if ($this->appliedAlready && !$this->isPropertyEnabled($property, $resourceClass) ) {
            return;
        }

        //make sure latitude and longitude are part of specs    
        if(!($this->isPropertyMapped(self::LAT, $resourceClass) && $this->isPropertyMapped(self::LON, $resourceClass)) ){
            return ;
        }

        $query=$this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->query;

        $values=[];
        foreach($this->properties as $prop=>$val){
            $this->properties[$prop]=$query->get($prop,null);
        }

        //distance is optional 
        if($this->properties[self::LAT]!=null && $this->properties[self::LON]!=null){
            if($this->properties['distance']==null)
                $this->properties['distance']=self::DISTANCE;
        }else{
            //may be we should raise exception 
            return;
        }

        $this->appliedAlready=True;

        // Generate a unique parameter name to avoid collisions with other filters
        $latParam = $queryNameGenerator->generateParameterName(self::LAT);
        $lonParam = $queryNameGenerator->generateParameterName(self::LON);
        $distParam = $queryNameGenerator->generateParameterName('distance');


        $locationWithinXKmDistance="(
            6371.0 * acos (
                cos ( radians(:$latParam) )
                * cos( radians(o.latitude) )
                * cos( radians(o.longitude) - radians(:$lonParam) )
                + sin ( radians(:$latParam) )
                * sin( radians(o.latitude) )
           )
        )<=:$distParam";

        $queryBuilder
            ->andWhere($locationWithinXKmDistance)
            ->setParameter($latParam, $this->properties[self::LAT])
            ->setParameter($lonParam, $this->properties[self::LON])
            ->setParameter($distParam, $this->properties['distance']);
    }

    // This function is only used to hook in documentation generators (supported by Swagger and Hydra)
    public function getDescription(string $resourceClass): array
    {
        if (!$this->properties) {
            return [];
        }

        $description = [];
        foreach ($this->properties as $property => $strategy) {
            $description["distance_$property"] = [
                'property' => $property,
                'type' => 'string',
                'required' => false,
                'swagger' => [
                    'description' => 'Find locations within given radius',
                    'name' => 'distance_filter',
                    'type' => 'filter',
                ],
            ];
        }

        return $description;
    }
}
```

The idea is we are expecting `latitude`, `longitude` and optionally `distance` parameters in query string. If on one of required param is missing filter is not invoked. If distance is missing we will assume default distance `10km`.

Since we have to [add DQL functions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language) for `acos`, `cos`,`sin` and `radians` , instead we use [doctrine extensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) as follow:

Install doctrine extensions:

`composer require beberlei/doctrineextensions`

> src/config/packages/doctrine_extensions.yaml

```
doctrine:
     orm:
         dql:
              numeric_functions:
                 acos: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Acos
                 cos: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Cos
                 sin: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Sin
                 radians: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Radians
```

> src/config/services.yaml

```
services:
    ....
    App\Filter\DistanceFilter:
      arguments: [ '@doctrine', '@request_stack', '@?logger', {latitude: ~, longitude: ~, distance: ~} ]
      tags:
          - { name: 'api_platform.filter', id: 'location.distance_filter' }
      autowire: false
      autoconfigure: false

    app.location.search_filter:
        parent:        'api_platform.doctrine.orm.search_filter'
        arguments:     [ {"city":"partial","postal_code":"partial","address":"partial"}]
        tags:          [ { name: 'api_platform.filter', id: 'location.search_filter' } ]
        autowire:  false
        autoconfigure: false
```

Configure api filters on location entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Dto\LocationOutput;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;

/**
 * Location
 * 
 * @ApiResource(
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "path"="/getLocationList", 
 *               "filters"={
 *                      "location.distance_filter",
 *                       "location.search_filter"
 *                }
 *           }
 *      },
 *      itemOperations={"get"},
 *      output=LocationOutput::class
 * )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the condition in your SQL, for example in your entity repository.

```
class YourEntityRepository {

    public function findByLongLatDist(float lat, float long, float dist) {
        // create your query builder here and return results
    }

}
```

Also check https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/find-points-within-a-distance-using-mysql to retrieve points using MySQL query. And this repository https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions to use specific MySQL functions.

Comment: I am not sure how I ll invoke that entity repository function. What if we want to do that calculation in php ? However, I ll explore your idea, I just want to know if its possible to filter object after they are retrieved from db .  Thanks for the gist

Comment: Maybe try this https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#creating-custom-doctrine-orm-filters